# How check if a string is substring with indexof [JAVASCRIPT]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a method:

```
function isSubString(word,array){}
```

This method, given an array of words and a word, tries if the word is a substring of the others words in array.

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){

        if(JSON.stringify(array[i]).indexOf(JSON.stringify(word))>0){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

For example `array=['home','dog']` and `word='ho'`;

Word `ho` is sub string of `home` but this method is wrong. Anyone can help me?

Comment: When comparing `index` use `> -1` or `!== -1`.

Comment: do you want the word to match all elements or at least one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `JSON.stringify()`, use  [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

> The `indexOf()` method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at `fromIndex`. Returns `-1` if the value is not found.

```
if(array[i].indexOf(word) >-1 ){
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
function isSubstring(word, array) {
  return array.some(function(el){return el.indexOf(word) != -1})
}

var array = ['home','dog']
var word = 'ho'
var isSub = isSubstring(word, array)

// Demo output
document.write(isSub)
```

if you want all elements to match the substring use [`array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead